# Java swing- using a boolean outside the scope in a mouseclicked event?

Tags: java, swing, button, mouseevent, actionlistener

Hi I was wondering how can you respond to different situations in a mouseclicked event from a button.  I currently have something like

```
boolean x = false;
btnExample.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {

    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
    .
    .
    .
```

I would like the first line in the mouseclicked to be an if statement checking if the boolean (x) is true/false.  I guess my issue is how do I get access to this variable (x) since it must be marked as final (which isn't what I want since I need to change it)?  I will be changing x to true at some point.

Comment: Why does x have to be marked as final?  Without seeing more I'd say just make x a field in your class.

Comment: why does it have to be marked as final?

Comment: If I try to use x how I have it, it says it cannot refer to non final variables inside inner classes defined in a different method.

Comment: To answer the title directly: You can't access variables outside of their scope.

Comment: Maybe it is reasonable to use JToggleButton in your case.

Comment: Thanks cruncher, way to contribute.

Comment: Why do you think you need a boolean variable? If we know the exact requirement (not your attempted solution) maybe we can suggest a better design.

Answer (score 2):

1. You're trying to use a local boolean variable inside of an anonymous inner class, and this only works if the field is final, to prevent the inner class's copy of the variable from being out of sync. The solution is to make the boolean a class field and it will be visible inside of the anonymous inner class.
2. It's not a good idea to use MouseListeners with JButtons. Use an ActionListener instead. Otherwise your button will not behave always as expected. For instance disabling the button will not inactivate the listener as it should.

---

e.g.,

```
public class Foo {
  private boolean myBooleanClassField = false;


}
```

Comment: What do you mean by making the boolean a class field?

Comment: Ahhhh your second point is exactly the reason why I am doing this.  Haha maybe I should use the actionlistener. Thanks.

Comment: @Robert: see edit above. The variable is declared in the class, not in a method or constructor.

Comment: That still doesn't solve the issue though.  The anonymous inner class cannot reference variables in say my main class unless they are marked as final.

Comment: Just a little thing.. "The solution is to make the boolean a class field.. " class field refers to static, i think you mean `instance field`

Comment: @Robert: you are wrong. A class field, a field that is declared **in the class** and not in a method or constructor, can be referenced by anonymous inner classes, and this is often done.

Answer (score 2):

1) Make the field a class field of the anonymous class.

```
btnExample.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
    private boolean x = false;

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
       //code here
    }
}
```

2) Or make a private inner class

```
private class MyMouseListener extends MouseAdapter {
    private boolean x = false;

     //or you can inject via constructor or setter

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
       //code here
    }
}
```

3) Or make `x` an instance variable from your class but this is only recommended if `x` is used or mutate in the class and not only in the anonymous class.

Example :

```
public class MyClass {

private boolean x = false;

 public MyClass(){

  btnExample.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
       x = true;
    }
  }
 }        
}
```

Comment: But other buttons need to have access to this variable as well.  This variable isn't confined to this one mouse listener.

Comment: @Robert make it as an instance variable then!

Comment: @Robert not at all! only mark as final if it's a local variable! See my 3 solutions. The third is what you need!